# AWS API Gateway websocket with spring boot backend

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I'm building an application using spring boot. I'm planning to add a chat feature to it via websocket. Considering that I'm hosting it on AWS, how can I integrate the websocket properly via api gateway websocket? Do I do my spring controller mapping for websocket via api gateway websocket endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway provides you with an option of HTTP integration, so you can keep your application in an ECS container and expose an endpoint that can be ingested by the API gateway side.